# Error count and $Error automatic variable not consistent

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I'm trying to grasp the `Write-Error` and `$Error` automatic variable with the code sample below, which is supposed to generate a single error:

```
function Test-Error
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    Write-Error -Message "Error message" -Category PermissionDenied -ErrorId SampleID
}

$Error.Clear()
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Test-Error
```

According to documentation:

> $Error Contains an array of error objects that represent the most
>   recent errors. The most recent error is the first error object in the
>   array $Error[0].

OK so let's take a look at error contents now:

```
$Error[0] | select -property *
```

This will print out the error, (I'm not pasting it here because it's not relevant to the question)

So according to docs this the error, but it looks like docs are wrong:

```
$Error[1] | select -property *
```

This will also print out something!

The question is how is that single error happens to be split into 2 pieces?

Isn't just `$Error[0]` supposed to contain last error as the docs say?

Obviously I did clear the variable so only single element is supposed to be in the array, not 2.

both elements seem to be pointing to single error, but what's the purpose of 2 array elements for single error?

and if the `$Error` variable happens to have 30 or so errors how do tell which *2* are relating to same error? because that means 60 elements for 30 errors!

Comment: `$errorActionPreference` or `-ErrorAction` is for handling non-terminating errors. You are telling PowerShell to halt for what would otherwise be uninterrupted write to the error stream. The intention for stopping is for capturing the exception and performing some resulting action. This is commonly used with `try {} catch {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other error is due to `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` - the error message that you did not post would have clarified it, the `Message` property is `The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Error message`. If you do not use that, you get only one element in `$Error`.

Comment: thank you, I did read about preference variable and there is no mention of setting a preference variable means bloating the $Error variable. one more reason not to rely on docs to much I guess.

Comment: In the meanwhile I also searched in the docs for related info, but there seems to be no mention of this. So MS leaves us with "find out yourself". Besides this I would not say not to rely on the docs - it does not tell you the opposite, it is "just" missing. Maybe, if you have time and care about future visitors of the docs, you could submit it somewhere on the MS sites that deal with undocumented features, so that they may add it.

Comment: I didn't mean to insult the docs, I really like MS documentation, thank you for suggestion, the issue posted here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5452

Comment: Nice job! Also that you shared the link here. Very well done.